# Minecraft - Redstone Sequence for Minecart Trap?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to create a simple catcher for a railway. I have the following set-up going on but there's a slight problem when you turn it off... It breaks since there's a gap. Is there a better way or someway I can switch up the delay between the two pistons? Btw, I do want to have it on 1 lever.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXqIK.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple mechanic. You just need the mechanic above, but without the repeaters.
[image: From the side]
[image: From the other side]
[image: From the back]
The piston that is pushing and pulling the red wool is sticky.
[image: Sticky piston proof]
When activated, whala!
[image: When activated]

Comment: Turning on the lever creates a nice track but turning the lever off, destroys the rail, which is what I'm having trouble with. I need something that gives the rail piston a delay when the circuit is powered.

Comment: For me, this worked. I don't know what problem you're having, because this works fine for me. It retracts and pushes forward correctly. Maybe you're forgetting yellow wool or that both pistons are sticky? If you want a delay you could put a repeater.